# How to prevent non-root user from changing IP address and network parameters?

Tags: networking, network-manager, ip, ip-address

As I wrote in subject - How to prevent non-root user from changing IP address and network parameters?

It's on Ubuntu 12.04.

I followed instructions on Sitepoint's link http://www.sitepoint.com/ubuntu-12-04-lts-precise-pangolin-networking-tips-and-tricks/, in Disable the Network Manager and ‘hard-code’ a static IP address section, but that does not works - end user is still capable to change network parameters.

Can you help me please how to solve my problem?

Answer (score 0):

What if you did

```
sudo chown root /etc/network/interfaces
```

and/or

```
sudo chmod 555 /etc/network/interfaces
```

Chmod changes the permissions, to read and execute only. that maens no one has the power to write to the file unless they sudo

chown makes the file the roots and stops other user from messing with it.

I think this will work...

Edits:

I don't know why this wont work

```
nano /etc/NetworkManager/NetworkManager.conf

managed=false
```

try this to remove the manager

```
sudo apt-get purge network-manager
```

Comment: it is root 555 already

Comment: How is the info being changed?

Comment: don't get you... file /etc/network/interfaces is already owned by root and permissions of it are 555

Comment: You said " end user is still capable to change network parameters."  How, by terminal, networkmanager ect?

Comment: yes, non-root user can change network parameters using network manager and i have to avoid that somehow.